# python - register all subclasses

Tags: python

I have a `class Step`, which I want to derive by many sub-classes. I want every class deriving from `Step` to be "registered" by a name I choose for it (not the class's name), so I can later call `Step.getStepTypeByName()`.

Something like this, only working :):

```
class Step(object):
    _STEPS_BY_NAME = {}

    @staticmethod
    def REGISTER(cls, name):
        _STEPS_BY_NAME[name] = cls

class Derive1(Step):
    REGISTER(Derive1, "CustomDerive1Name")
    ...

class Derive2(Step):
    REGISTER(Derive2, "CustomDerive2Name")
    ...
```

Comment: Out of curiosity - why do you need such solution?

Comment: @matino I want to automatically be able to serialize all my `Step`s to XML, where the XML node has the custom name. I want to later be able to read the XML node and generate a `Step` from it. So I need to know the Step type by the node's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution do not work for three reasons.

The first one is that `_STEPS_BY_NAME` only exists as an attribute of the `Step` class, so `Step.REGISTER` cannot access `_STEPS_BY_NAME` without a reference to the `Step` class. IOW you have to make it a `classmethod` (cf below)

The second one is that you need to explicitely use `Step.REGISTER(cls)` - the name `REGISTER` does not exist outside the `Step` class.

The third reason is that within a `class` statement's body, the class object has not yet been created not bound to it's name, so you cannot not reference the class itself at this point.

IOW, you'd want this instead:

```
class Step(object):
    _STEPS_BY_NAME = {}

    # NB : by convention, "ALL_UPPER" names denote pseudo-constants
    @classmethod
    def register(cls, name):
        # here `cls` is the current class 
        cls._STEPS_BY_NAME[name] = stepclass

class Derive1(Step):
    ...

Step.register(Derive1, "CustomDerive1Name")


class Derive2(Step):
    ...

Step.register(Derive2, "CustomDerive2Name")
```

Now with a minor modification to `Step.register` you could use it as a class decorator, making things much clearer:

```
class Step(object):
    _STEPS_BY_NAME = {}

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, name):
        def _register(stepclass):
            cls._STEPS_BY_NAME[name] = stepclass
            return stepclass 
        return _register 


@Step.register("CustomDerive1Name")
class Derive1(Step):
    ...



@Step.register("CustomDerive2Name")
class Derive2(Step):
    ...
```

**As a last note:** unless you have a compelling reason to register your subclasses in the base class itself, it might be better to use module-level variables and functions (a Python module is actually a kind of singleton):

```
# steps.py

class Step(object):
    #....

_STEPS_BY_NAME = {}

def register(name):
   def _register(cls):
       _STEPS_BY_NAME[name] = cls
       return cls
   return _register

def get_step_class(name):
    return _STEPS_BY_NAME[name]
```

And in your other modules

```
import steps

@steps.register("CustomDerive1Name")
class Derive1(steps.Step):
    # ...
```

The point here is to avoid giving too many responsabilies to your `Step` class. I don't know your concrete use case so I can't tell which design best fits your need, but I've been using this last one on quite a few projects and it always worked fine so far.

Comment: Nice. If it's a classmethod, shouldn't I invoke it using the actual class, i.e `Derive1.register(...)`, `Derive2.register(...)`?

Comment: Please re-read my explanations: if using the class decorator solution (which I highly recommand as it's much easier to use and read), you can _not_ use "the actual (sub)class" since it does not exist yet  (`class` statements are executable statements, all this happens at runtime, not at compile time). Also, explicitely calling `Step.register` makes the intent more obvious.

Comment: Oh. Now I get it. Didn't know about this decorator syntax. It's nice.

Comment: @EladWeiss actually there was a typo in the decorator syntax (cf the edited snippet) <g>

Comment: Works perfect now! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :-) - but you may want to read my last edit too.

Answer (score 0):

You are close. Use this

```
class Step(object):
    pass

class Derive1(Step):
    pass

class Derive2(Step):
    pass

_STEPS_BY_NAME = {
    'foo': Step,
    'bar': Derive1,
    'bar': Derive2
}

def get_step_by_name(name):
    return _STEPS_BY_NAME[name]
```

Warning: there might be better approaches depending on what you are trying to achieve. Such a mapping from strings to methods is a maintenance nightmare. If you want to change the name of a method, you would have to remember to change it in multiple place. You won't get any autocomplete help from your IDE either.

Comment: I think OP wanted it to be "automatic". Your code violates the [Open/Closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle), whereas OP's violates the [Single Responsibilty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: @PeterWood Yes. (Even though I could not express it in words). Also thanks for the link. I'll see what I'm violating.

Comment: Note that you _can_ have the registry at the module level (fixing the single resp. violation) and still dynamically register Step subclasses (fixing the open/closed violation), cf the last note of my answer.